# mail clients are unable to connect to mail server behind proxy

Tags: linux, unix, proxy, squid

I configured proxy server.Before I configure proxy mail clients works fine.Now I am unable to send and receive mails.We are using mail server in cpanel.How to bypass these settings in proxy server? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution.

in mail client like outlook or thunderbird. In proxy settings leave the blank in ip and port for socks option.
thats it now you can access mail from your client apps.